# Wordpress - display shortcode for user certain user role

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to display a shortcode of a specific user role. The user role is **customer**.

```
global $current_user; 
get_currentuserinfo(); 
if ( user_can( $current_user, "customer" ) ){ 
    echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id="2"]');
}
```

Comment: Look at [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5047/how-to-check-if-a-user-is-in-a-specific-role?noredirect=1&lq=1). I think you will get the answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( in_array( 'shop_manager', (array) $user->roles ) ) { // user role condition
    echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id="2"]');
}
```